# use of combobox ValueMember and DisplayMember

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have an excel file which has two columns (1. Name and 2. Value) which I want to bind to a ComboBox.

When I set the `DisplayMember` to *name* it shows the all the values from the Name column in the Excel file.

I would like to get a similar dropdown as in asp.net controls with a text field and a value field so that when I select the text field then value field can be obtained using background code.

How can I do in ComboBox(WinForms)?

i am using following code.

```
String strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source="C:\vipin.xls"+ "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();          
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [name] FROM [Sheet1$] where Component=1 ", strConn);          
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;            
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that solves your problem by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign value for ValueMember of combo box.

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [name],[value] FROM [Sheet1$] where Component=1 ", strConn);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "value";
comboBox1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

HTH.

Comment: when i using this code the display member shows all the value of name column but the value comes each of display member is:System.Data.DataRowView . what i do for value member.

Comment: i was not able to accessing the value of it. now i got the point .

Comment: To retrieve value member, you can use SelectedValue property of combobox.

Comment: I have used the combobox.selectedvalue and its working for me Thanks,