# Combobox ValueMember

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I use this code for populate the combobox but It is possible associate at column1 ex: name on the column 2 ex; ID? with use the cmbbox.valuemember =

```
private DataTable BindData() 
        { 
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\YOURDB.mdb; PersSecurity Info=False;")) /your connectionsting 
            { 
                using (var dAd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select column1 from Table ", conn)) //select query from your DB 
                { 

                    var dSet = new DataTable(); 
                    try 
                    { 
                        conn.Open(); 

                        dAd.Fill(dSet); 

                        return dSet; 

                    } 
                    catch 
                    { 
                        throw; 
                    } 
                    finally 
                    { 
                        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

buttonevent

```
var dt = BindData(); 
        cmbBox.DataSource = dt; 
        cmbBox.DisplayMember = "column1"; //Display Table Column on your DB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About DisplayMember & ValueMember property of Combobox, this may help:

[use of combobox ValueMember and DisplayMember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367860/use-of-combobox-valuemember-and-displaymember/8367960#8367960)