# Assign value member from database to combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, combobox, database-connection

I'm trying to select two columns from my database, one to make it displaymember in my combobox and the other one to make it the valuemember

My code goes like:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Clinic\Clinic\Clinc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ClinicName,ClinicCode from Clinic",con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ClinicName";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ClinicCode";
```

It does fetch the data from database and display it well, but can't set the valuemember.

When I try to print it to label to see it, the label displays "cliniccode"

What's wrong ?

Comment: can you show us the code you're using to print the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `comboBox1.SelectedValue` property to get or set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `comboBox1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;`?

[use of combobox ValueMember and DisplayMember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367860/use-of-combobox-valuemember-and-displaymember/)

Comment: thank you , ya i was missing that i'm learning programming by myself and your all being so helpful

Comment: You're welcome =] everyone has to start at the bottom at some point ^_^